# Getting re-written list of terms for FuzzyQuery

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, scoring

**I'm using Lucene.NET 4.8-beta00005**

Given a fuzzy query

```
var fuzzyQuery = new FuzzyQuery(new Term(NameField, term));
```

What is the proper way of getting the list of terms/transpositions (and boosts assigned by `FuzzyQuery` to each of them) that will end up as a BooleanQuery after the query is re-written.

I'm looking at `FuzzyQuery.Rewrite` and then extracting the resulting list from the `BooleanQuery` from within the re-written query, but the documentation on `Rewrite` seems to suggest using `FuzzyQuery.GetTermsEnum` instead, and I cannot figure out how to use `FuzzyQuery.GetTermsEnum`.

I need this for my custom scoring using a `CustomScoreProvider` where I would score a document match at a 100 when all terms from the query exactly match the document and would also use the boosts assigned by `FuzzyQuery` to the transpositions to adjust the scoring so that all non-exact matches don't result into a score of 100.

Comment: Can I [recommend against what you are trying to do](https://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ScoresAsPercentages)? As far as `GetTermsEnum`, it's protected, you would need to call it from a subclass of FuzzyQuery.

Comment: I need this type of scoring so that it is possible to filter by score and only show complete matches, I'm searching against the OFAC lists and need a behavior similar to their own search page which has a filter which by default only shows complete matches (scored 100)

Comment: I think the better way to accomplish that would be composing the right query, instead of looking for a "perfect" score. If you want to only show docs in which all subqueries match, use required ('must') clauses for those subqueries. That is, you would search for `field1:term field2:term` is that filter was turned off, and `+field1:term +field2:term` if it was turned on.

Comment: That would work if I only needed to show documents scoring 100, but it should be possible to lower the minimal score and then it should show more results. https://sanctionssearch.ofac.treas.gov/

Comment: And for that, I would direct you again to the article I linked above. You *can* specify a [minimumShouldMatch](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.Builder.html#setMinimumNumberShouldMatch-int-) on your boolean query, which may get you what you are looking for (ie. maybe a 75% match means minimumShouldMatch = 3 when you have 4 subqueries). However, trying to treat *scores* as percentages is problematic.